# Print variable to CONSOLE

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I'm trying to print variable to CONSOLE.

I need to print only using IF condition to check variable is empty or not.

I tried below code on JSR223 but not working

````
if (${__javaScript(vars.get("err") != null)})
{
    ${__logn(Complete,OUT)}
    } else {
        ${__logn(ErrorMessage=${err},OUT)}
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `${}` syntax in JSR223, I think you mean to do the following

```
if (vars.get("err") == null) {
    OUT.println("Complete");
} else {
    OUT.println("ErrorMessage=" + vars.get("err"));
}
```

Comment: can i use if condition in JSR223 just like using it JAVA.

Comment: @pengu1nnn yes, it's a java if condition (groovy has similar syntax to java)

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts because:

1. Their will conflict with [Groovy GString template engine](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)
2. [JMeter Variables will be cached](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and only first occurrence will be used

Example alternative code:

```
vars.get('err') ? println('ErrorMessage=' + vars.get('err')) : println('Complete')
```

More information:

- [Groovy Ternary Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator)
- [Groovy Truth](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: is there any difference between OUT.println and println? I think OUT.println is print to console. Println is print to log screen.

Comment: No difference, 4 symbols less to type